# Calculate the gradient of a function over a matrix with element-wise terms

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, image-processing

Consider the following problem
$$ 
J(v) = \frac{\lambda}{2}|| g - v ||_2^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \phi_\alpha((\delta_x^hv)_{i,j})+\phi_\alpha((\delta_y^hv)_{i,j})
$$
where $ g,v $ is a matrix of image of size $m\times n$ and the definition of $\phi_\alpha$ is below:
$$
\phi_\alpha(t) = |t| - \alpha \log\left(1+\frac{|t|}{\alpha}\right)
$$
and $\delta_x^h$ and $\delta_y^h$ is the gradient of image $v$. I need to calculate the gradient of $J$ to minimize $J$ using gradient descent to denoise a image.

What i've calculated is
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial v} = \lambda(v-g) + \Bigg(\frac{(\delta_x^hv)_{i,j}(\delta_{xx}^hv)_{i,j}}{\alpha +|(\delta_x^hv)_{i,j}|} + \frac{(\delta_y^hv)_{i,j}(\delta_{yy}^hv)_{i,j}}{\alpha +|(\delta_y^hv)_{i,j}|}\Bigg)_{1\leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n}
$$
where the $(\delta_{xx}^hv)_{i,j}$ and $(\delta_{yy}^hv)_{i,j}$ are the second order derivative of an image v.

But when i use this to do the gradient descent, the result is pretty bad. The image i got hasn't been denoised no matter how i change the value of number of iteration and the value of step. Can somebody point me out where i've made the mistake about the gradient of $J$? I've a hint that maybe the terms $\delta_{xx}^hv$ and $\delta_{yy}^hv$ might be wrong, but what's the gradient of gradient of image($\delta_x^hv$, $\delta_y^hv$, more specifically, $$\frac{\partial \delta_x^hv}{\partial v} \text{ and } \frac{\partial \delta_y^hv}{\partial v}$$ How can i calculate it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose the problem is about some kind of minimization? Right now you just define a function $J(v)$ but don't mention what should be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Those image "gradients" are really convolutions, so let's denote them by
$$\eqalign{
&A*V &= \delta^h_xV,\quad &&B*V  &= \delta^h_yV \\
d(\!&A*V) &= A*dV,\quad &d(\!&B*V) &= B*dV \\
}$$
where $(*)$ is the convolution product, $V$ is the image
and $(A,B)$ are the kernel matrices.

Given a matrix $X$, define the elementwise functions
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm sign}(X) &\implies {\tt1} &= S\odot S \\
A &= |X| = S\odot X \quad&\implies X &= S\odot A \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

When the scalar function $\phi$ is applied elementwise to $X$
we can calculate its subdifferential as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= S\odot X - \alpha\log\left({\tt1}+\frac{S\odot X}{\alpha}\right) \\
d\phi &= S\odot dX - \frac{\alpha\,(S\odot dX)}{\alpha{\tt1}+S\odot X} \\
 &= \left(S - \frac{\alpha S}{\alpha{\tt1}+S\odot X}\right)\odot dX \\
 &= \left(\frac{S\odot S\odot X}{\alpha{\tt1}+S\odot X}\right)\odot dX \\
 &= \left(\frac{X}{\alpha{\tt1}+|X|}\right)\odot dX \\
}$$
where $\Big(\frac{X}{Y}\Big)$ denotes elementwise/Hadamard division.

Applying this to one of the problematic terms.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal J}_A &={\tt1}:\phi(A*V) \\
d{\cal J}_A
  &={\tt1}:\left(\frac{A*V}{\alpha{\tt1}+|A*V|}\right)\odot(A*dV)\\
  &= \left(\frac{A*V}{\alpha{\tt1}+|A*V|}\right):(A*dV) \\
  &= (JAJ)*\left(\frac{A*V}{\alpha{\tt1}+|A*V|}\right):dV \\
\frac{\partial{\cal J}_A}{\partial V}
  &= (JAJ)*\left(\frac{A*V}{\alpha{\tt1}+|A*V|}\right) \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$\,M:N={\rm Tr}(M^TN)$

The Frobenius and Hadamard products commute, i.e.
$\,A:B\odot C=A\odot B:C$

$J$ is the [Exchange Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) which is used to "flip" the kernel.

Finally, the full function can be dispatched as
$$\eqalign{
{\cal J} &= \frac{\lambda}{2}\|V-G\|^2_F + {\cal J}_A + {\cal J}_B \\
\frac{\partial{\cal J}}{\partial V}
 &= \lambda(V-G)
 + \frac{\partial{\cal J}_A}{\partial V}
 + \frac{\partial{\cal J}_B}{\partial V} \\
}$$
This is very similar to the result that you obtained, but you are calculating the gradient of the gradient by re-using the same kernel, i.e.
$$A*(A*V)$$
whereas you need to "reflect" the kernel through its center
$$(JAJ)*(A*V)$$
However, if $A$ is centrosymmetric (e.g. a Gaussian) then $JAJ=A$.